# Is there a library or guide for publishing data via GData (Google Data Protocol)?

Tags: odata, gdata

[GData](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/) is Google's version of [OData](http://www.odata.org/). It is what Google uses to publish a number of [their data sources](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/directory.html). With OData there are both client and server side tools, but I am only seeing [client libraries for GData](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/client-libraries.html). Are there server libraries for GData?

Answer (score 0):

More research looks like GDAta is only published by Google, and then end users can only create clients. By design it is a one way system.